# After upgrading from php5.5.9 to php5.6, What's the equivalent of php5enmod?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, php-5.6

In ubuntu server, I used to install modules for php5.5.9 like for example mcrypt with apt-get, and then I enabled it with `sudo php5enmod mcrypt`.

Now I've upgraded to php5.6, and I missed a module to work with PHPThumb in Laravel 4.2, which requires either GID or Imagick to modify images. So I did :

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5.6-imagick
```

Then to enable this module I did :

```
$ sudo php5enmod imagick
```

It returns this error : "WARNING: Module imagick ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php5/mods-available" . Which is normal because it exists under /etc/php/5.6/mods-available.

Is there a command to enable it like:

```
$ sudo php5enmod imagick --path=/etc/php/5.6/mods-available
```

Or :

```
$ sudo php5.6enmod imagick
```

Or could I link php5enmod to php/5.6 path instead?

Comment: For first check "$ php -v" and "$ php -m" then update your question

Comment: I had disable php5.5 and enabled php5.6 with a2enmod. So actual version is 5.6.

Comment: try it in CLI mode

Comment: But I found my mistake. php5.5 was using gd.ini in mods-available, which works with Mews/PHPThumb in Laravel 4.2. In php5.6 I only install imagick so php/5.6/mods-available contained imagick.ini which could not b used with Phpthumb probably because of config settings. Once I install php5.6-gd module in my staging server, My pictures are able to be uploaded and managed by PHPThumb again. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try phpenmod insted of php5enmod or php5.6enmod

Comment: if u want to use php5enmod then dosudo ln -s /usr/sbin/phpenmod /usr/sbin/php5enmod

Comment: Thanks. But it was my mistake as I mentioned. So I can't even accept my solution as an accepted answer, because imagik was already enabled in php5.6 .

Comment: phpenmod  Worked for me on php5.6